# XPath attribute selection bug in Chrome?

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

So I have the following HTML:

```
<div myID='carousel'>
   <div>
    <div>
     <h3>First Text</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div myID='carousel'>
   <div>
    <div>
     <h3>Second Text</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the second carousel - i.e. that with `Second Text`

I can get the `h3` segment using `$x('//div[./h3[contains(text(),"Second Text")]]')`

However I want the parent div with that `myID` - any ideas?

Comment: @kjhughes Just checking it - number 2 is the one I want - however it didnt seem to work

Comment: Its returning `[]` - I want it to return the the second div
The second one makes sense to me so I also dont understand why its not working. Furthermore, if i try them each without the `and` it returns expected

Comment: Thats still not it - so if I do
`//div[h3 = "Second Text"]` it returns something. If i do `//div[@myID="carousel"]` it also returns something. But with the `and` i.e. `//div[h3 = "Second Text" and @myID="carousel"]` it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure XML/XPath Answer

Given this XML,

```
<html>
  <div myID='carousel'>
     <div>
       <div>
         <h3>First Text</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div myID='carousel'>
     <div>
       <div>
         <h3>Second Text</h3>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Then:

1. This XPath,

   ```
   //div[.//h3 = "Second Text"]
   ```

   selects all `div` elements containing a descendant `h3` element whose string value is `"Second Text"`.
2. This XPath,

   ```
   //div[div/div/h3 = "Second Text" and @myID="carousel"]
   ```

   selects all `div` elements containing a descendant `h3` element whose string value is `"Second Text"`, provided the `div` element also has a `myID` attribute value equal to `"carousel"`.
3. This XPath,

   ```
   //div[div/div/h3 = "Second Text" and @myID]
   ```

   selects all `div` elements containing a descendant `h3` element whose string value is `"Second Text"`, provided the `div` element also has a `myID` attribute, regardless of its value.

### Google Chrome XPath Answer

Here's the confusing part:  XPaths **#2** and **#3** select ***nothing*** in Chrome via `$x()`.  (WTH?)

The reason is that [**in Chrome, XPath requires lowercasing to query attributes**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179453&thanks=179453&ts=1362167145), perhaps motivated by [XHTML's requirement that element and attribute names must be in lower case](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2).

**Chrome work-around:**  Test `@myid` rather than `@myID`.

Comment: I've taught you enough that you should be able to take it from here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - I got it: `$x('//*[div/div/h3 = "Related Products" and @data-id="decoratedCarouselContainer"]')`

Comment: Answer updated to account for confusion related to Chrome XPath selection of attributes that are capitalized.  (Ugh)

Comment: @userMod2:  I've removed all of my comments except the key last one.   You might want to clean-up your comment trail too now that we've figured this out.  Thanks.